# Detecting Carriage Return (\r\n) in JAVA

Tags: java, carriage-return

I'm sending a message into a socket(local) in Java with \n\r after each message and at the end I send empty line, such that:

ROCK\r\n

PAPER\r\n

\r\n

I have to get the ROCK and PAPER into a string and using the following code:

```
        while ((sc = in1.readLine()) != null)
        {
            clientMsg += sc + "sep";
            System.out.println(sc);
            System.out.println("end");
        }
```

However, this cannot detect the empty line in the message and terminate while loop, until it stays there and does nothing. The output for the input:

ROCK\r\n
PAPER\r\n
\r\n

is as follows:

```
ROCK    
end
PAPER
end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop will terminate when the stream reaches `EOF` end of file because you're checking for `null` and not for an empty line. To do what you want you can change the loop's condition to something like this: `while ((sc = in1.readLine()) != null && !sc.isEmpty())`